# Conflict between DT::datatable and haven_labelled

Tags: r, dt, r-labelled

There seems to be a conflict between `DT::datatable` and `haven_labelled` data types.

This works fine:

```
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(labelled)
testDf <- tibble(a=c("one","two"),
                 b=c(1,2)) 
datatable(testDf)
```

This does not:

```
test2Df <- testDf %>%
  set_value_labels(b = c("First"=1, "Second"=2))
datatable(test2Df)
```

Yielding the following error:

> Error: C stack usage  15923728 is too close to the limit

Including `library(haven)` doesn't help.

Poking around for info about C stack errors points to deep recursive functions, which a 2x2 table is not. I've used `DT` to display dataframes with `haven_labelled` data types in the past, so I'm guessing this is a recent bug with one or the other. My versions are as follows:

- R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
- Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
- Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
- labelled_2.12.0 DT_0.29         dplyr_1.1.2

Comment: I cannot replicate the behavior. I tested on R 4.2.1 but used the same package version numbers. Are you sure this happens for you in a fresh R session using the exact code you've shared here?

Comment: @RitchieSacramento My R was running `htmltools_0.5.3` so that could be it.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yeah, I'm running `htmltools_0.5.6` as well. I'll head over to GitHub and file an issue.